# GoJS makeSvg of contextMenu

Tags: javascript, svg, gojs

I am displaying additional details to the Node when rightclicking it. 
Now i want to display these details somewhere else when the Node is only selected, not rightclicked.

Is there a way to make an SVG from the adornment/contextMenu

I tried acting as if the contextMenu was a normal Node

I called

```
diagram.makeSVG({
    parts: diagram.selection.first().adornments.first()
})
```

Or

```
diagram.makeSVG({
    parts: diagram.selection.first().contextMenu
})
```

but neither worked.

I always get the error "cannot set property 'reset' of undefined"

Trying

```
diagram.makeSVG({
    parts: diagram.selection.first().adornments 
})
```

worked without an error somehow, which is odd, as `adornments` gives an iterator. With that the SVG was created (i saw this looking at the HTML where i put it afterwards), but without any contents.

How do i create an SVG from the contextMenu **properly**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the "parts" property of the argument of the **Diagram.makeSvg** method expects a collection, i.e. an **Iterable**.

Second if you want **Diagram.makeSvg** or **Diagram.makeImage** to render **Adornment**s or other temporary **Part**s, you need to specify "showTemporary".

    `// assuming myDiagram.selection.count > 0:
    var svg = myDiagram.makeSvg({
      parts: myDiagram.selection.first().adornments,
      showTemporary: true
    });`

This will include any context menu that is showing for the selected part.

Third, if you just want a rendering of a GoJS context menu:

    `var cm = myDiagram.selection.first().findAdornment("ContextMenu");
    if (cm === null) return;
    var ads = new go.List();
    ads.add(cm);
    var svg = myDiagram.makeSvg({
      parts: ads,
      showTemporary: true
    });`